# How to prove $f^{-1}(V) \cong f^{-1}(U) \times_U V$, where $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $U$ be an affine open subset of $Y$, and $V \subseteq U$ an open subset of $Y$. 
I am trying to prove 
$$
f^{-1}(V) \cong f^{-1}(U) \times_U V.
$$
I thought it's just a diagram chasing but it is not working out.. Any explanation is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: By definition of inverse image $f^{-1}(U)=X\times_Y U$. Thus $f^{-1}(U)\times_U V=(X\times_Y U)\times_U V=X\times_Y V=f^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for this! How does one establish $f^{-1}(U) = X \times_Y U$? It is easy to define $f^{-1}(U) \to X \times_Y U$ by drawing a commutative diagram, but I've been struggling to find the inverse...

Comment: You can check that $f^{-1}(U)$ satisfies the universal property of fiber product.

Comment: @eggplant Could you possibly give me more details? I tried it but I could not make it work...

Comment: @JohnnyT. We have to show that if $g \colon Z \to X$ and $h \colon Z \to U$ coincides in Y, $g$ uniquely factors through $f^{-1}(U)$. At first construct a continuous map between underlying topological spaces, and then think about sheaf homomorphism.